# Android Studio can only detect Xiomi redmi 4x but can't detect my other phones after connecting

Tags: android-studio-2.3

I ran my android projects on my Asus zenfone 3 and Walton primo Gh2. But after connecting Xiomi redmi 4x and running the project app on xiomi none of my other phones are detected by android studio. It can only detect my Xiomi redmi 4x. I am in serious trouble. I am sure my every settings are okay as I have ran my apps on those phones as well before this happened. This is serious trouble. Anybody with a solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are new to Android Studio. Anyway you need to manually make your devices ADB interfaces to make sure the android studio can detect them. How will you do that. Here...

http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I upgraded my android studio from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 and that is why my other phone drivers also needed an upgrade. My problem has been fixed :)